# how to call a friend function which use to overload the operator "<<"?

Tags: c++

.h file

```
class MyString{
private:
    int size;
    int capacity;
    char *data;

public:
    MyString( );
    MyString(const char *);
    void displayState( ostream &out );
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, MyString&);
};
```

.cpp

```
void MyString::displayState( ostream& out ){
    out << "Size: " << this->size << endl;
    out << "Capacity: " << this->capacity << endl;
    out << "Data: " << this->data << endl;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, MyString& myStr){
    for (int i = 0; i < myStr.size; i++){
        out << myStr.data[i]<<" ";
    }
    return out;
}
```

I didn't put out my constructor, because I hope I can protect my code

main.cpp

```
  char array[20] = {'1','2','4','g','1',
                      '2','6','b','v','c',
                      'b','c','b','q','b',
                      'p','b','q','m'};
    MyString testStr2(array);

    testStr2.displayState(cout);
```

and the output is

```
Size: 19
Capacity: 20
Data: 124g126bvcbcbqbpbqm
```

my code want to make my output like

```
Size: 19
Capacity: 20
Data: 1 2 4 g 1 2 6 b v c b c b q b p b q m
```

when I delete the friend function. my output is still the same. I just don't know why when I call the display function, and the operator << did't be overload

Comment: What does "_I didn't put out my constructor, because I hope I can protect my code_" mean?

Comment: means I have make my constructor, but I didn't put it on this website

Comment: That's probably a mistake. Unless you have a constructor doing super secret things, post it so people can take that into consideration too. _If_ it contains super secret things, move those out when creating your [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

1. Your title has a possible typo? You are overloading `operator<<` in code, but you are asking about overloading `operator>>`.
2. If my guess of the typo is right, it's because you **did not called** `ostream& operator<< (ostream&, MyString&);` **at all**.
   In your `void MyString::displayState( ostream& out )` function, you are calling

```cpp
out << "Data: " << this->data << endl;
```

which is calling `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)`

EDIT for addition: As for how to call your function, you defined that `operator<<` to accept an `ostream&` and `MyString&`. So you simply call it by `std::cout<<testStr2;`
in your `main()`.

Comment: yes my title is wrong and I can't find the way to change it.

Comment: I did't call my operator, so how to call it?

Comment: @hideonbush I added to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the error in your example, but managed this to get the result:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyString{
private:
    int size;
    int capacity;
    char *data;

public:
    MyString();
    MyString(char *, size_t sz);
    void displayState( ostream &out);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyString& dt);
};


MyString::MyString() {

}

MyString::MyString(char *cstr, size_t sz) {
    data = cstr;
    size = sz;
}

void MyString::displayState(ostream &out) {
    out << *this << endl;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const MyString& myStr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myStr.size; i++){
        out << myStr.data[i] << " ";
    }
    return out;
}

int main() {
    char array[20] = {'1', '2', '4', 'g', '1',
                        '2', '6', 'b', 'v', 'c',
                        'b', 'c', 'b', 'q', 'b',
                        'p', 'b', 'q', 'm'};
    MyString testStr2(array, 20);

    testStr2.displayState(cout);
}
```

> > 1 2 4 g 1 2 6 b v c b c b q b p b q m